# How to write a text into plotly heat map in r?

Tags: r, text, heatmap, plotly

Hello I make a heat map with `plotly`. The code is:

```
     plot_ly(z = ~df$MonetaryClass, 
        x = ~df$RecencyClass, 
        y = ~df$FrequencyClass, 
        type = "heatmap") %>% 
  colorbar(title = 'Monetary Class',
           limits = c(1,5), 
           tickmode = 'array', 
           tickvals = c(1,2,3,4,5)) %>%
  layout(title = "RFM Analyse",
         xaxis = list(title = 'Recency Class',
                      tickmode = 'array',
                      tickvals = c(1, 2,3,4,5),
                      ticktext = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
         ),
         yaxis = list(title = 'Frequency Class',
                      tickmode = 'array',
                      tickvals = c(1, 2,3,4,5),
                      ticktext = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
         )
  )
```

Here is a sample of 100 of my data frame, and the information of `dput()` :

```
     structure(list(RecencyClass = c(3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 
4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 5, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5, 
1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 
4, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 5, 
3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 
5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5), FrequencyClass = c(4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 5, 3, 1, 
5, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 
4, 4, 5, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 2, 1, 
4, 5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2), MonetaryClass = c(5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 
5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 
2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5, 
2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 4, 3)), .Names = c("RecencyClass", "FrequencyClass", 
"MonetaryClass"), row.names = c(24908L, 34164L, 27970L, 23648L, 
35944L, 35581L, 7825L, 27857L, 26043L, 31093L, 27026L, 13607L, 
8689L, 18196L, 39464L, 37304L, 9820L, 6867L, 35361L, 4767L, 18345L, 
8840L, 29486L, 11414L, 13718L, 60L, 31892L, 41103L, 13347L, 33299L, 
41563L, 8950L, 16L, 568L, 21384L, 25256L, 24005L, 30861L, 6025L, 
25098L, 5800L, 20559L, 2362L, 20797L, 11256L, 40490L, 9163L, 
3282L, 29174L, 5965L, 38331L, 11068L, 31018L, 28535L, 11793L, 
16171L, 37278L, 25937L, 5976L, 19566L, 18754L, 37055L, 11249L, 
13414L, 27966L, 31049L, 11150L, 15701L, 42887L, 11334L, 10880L, 
16532L, 44559L, 18162L, 9545L, 7810L, 3715L, 10128L, 42163L, 
16488L, 8926L, 6416L, 17789L, 4352L, 32966L, 10045L, 26614L, 
12601L, 10906L, 3122L, 4696L, 15936L, 18048L, 34864L, 41047L, 
24615L, 41413L, 39479L, 40317L, 37389L), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see I have 25 boxes insight my matrix. Is it possible to write a self chosen text in every box ? For example on box "1" Frequency and "1" Recency the blue-black one on the bottom left corner something like " I like beer". Or on "5" and "5" the yellow one in the upper right corner,something like "I like CSGO". 
I tried it with `text` but it don't work for me.

Comment: I tried to make a 5x5 Matrix with the required sentences, but I don't know how to match these new matrix with my plotly?

Answer (score 4):

First define the `5x5` text matrix, then add it to the data frame and then use `add_annotations`:

```
txt <- matrix(LETTERS[1:25], nrow=5) # define your 5x5 text matrix
df$txt <- txt[as.matrix(df[,1:2])]
library(plotly)
plot_ly(z = ~df$MonetaryClass, 
        x = ~df$RecencyClass, 
        y = ~df$FrequencyClass, 
        type = "heatmap") %>% 
  colorbar(title = 'Monetary Class',
           limits = c(1,5), 
           tickmode = 'array', 
           tickvals = c(1,2,3,4,5)) %>%
  layout(title = "RFM Analyse",
         xaxis = list(title = 'Recency Class',
                      tickmode = 'array',
                      tickvals = c(1, 2,3,4,5),
                      ticktext = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
         ),
         yaxis = list(title = 'Frequency Class',
                      tickmode = 'array',
                      tickvals = c(1, 2,3,4,5),
                      ticktext = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
         )
  ) %>%
  add_annotations(x = df$RecencyClass,
                  y = df$FrequencyClass,
                  text = df$txt, 
                  showarrow = FALSE,
                  ax = 20,
                  ay = -20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could add the text via [`add_annotations`](https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/#multiple-annotations).

- Specify the x and y coordinates (in the example below relative to x and y-axis via `xref = 'x'` and `yref = 'y'`)
- Add the text via `text`
- Remove the default arrow with `showarrow = FALSE`

[image]

```
anno_x <- c(1, 5)
anno_y <- c(1, 5)
anno_text <- c('I like beer', 'I like CSGO')

p <- plot_ly(
  x = c(1:5), 
  y = c(1:5),
  z = matrix(rnorm(9), nrow = 5, ncol = 5),
  type='heatmap') %>% add_annotations(x = anno_x, y = anno_y, text = anno_text, xref = 'x', yref = 'y', showarrow = FALSE, font=list(color='black'))

p
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you both.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a plot of `type=heatmap`, you can supply it a `texttemplate` parameter which defines what text is shown in each field.

This method is useful for those who are looking to write text to each field, based on data already present in their dataset. In the below example I'm mapping the z value to text and displaying the first decimal ("0.0") of the value.

```
plot_ly(z = ~df$MonetaryClass, 
    x = ~df$RecencyClass, 
    y = ~df$FrequencyClass, 
    type = "heatmap",
    texttemplate = "%{z:.1f}"
)
```

Read more about the `texttemplate` parameter here:
https://plotly.com/r/reference/heatmap/